# Java workflow with fork / join capabilities

Tags: java, python, workflow

I'm a Linux Python programmer with a (long) past Java experience

I need a reference to a workflow management system that supports async fork/join, I understand that [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm) does, though I prefer using Spring but could not understand if [Spring Workflow](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow) support forking as well. or is there a Python system that supports it?

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring web flow is not a BPM engine, it is a web framework based on workflow page navigation.
You can look at [Activity](http://www.activiti.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You could look through this list of [Open Source Workflow Engines in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines) and check the features list of each tool to see if one of them supports asynchronous fork/join.

You reference Spring Workflow, but actually link to [Spring Web Flow](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow). There is a [Spring Workflow](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-workflow) extension project in incubator status; is this what you meant? From its web page:

> The Workflow extension brings Spring to the world of workflow programming. Jan Machacek originally started this extension because he was not happy with the complexity of other workflow management libraries. The Spring Workflow extension treats all components of the workflow as first-class Spring beans. As a result, your flows, states and transitions can take advantage of all features in the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using Spring than in my opinion the natural choice for you would to to check out the [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) project. Camel supports most of [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) where you can fork, join, process asynchronously, whatever you want.